# Anchor and Jquery : doesn't want to scroll on top

Tags: jquery, hash, anchor

I've simple question about link with anchor and Jquery.

```
<a href="#" id="link">A Link</a>

<script>
    $("#link").click(function() {
        //some actions
    }
</script>
```

How , when i click on the link, not to follow the link. I mean the page back up everytime..

Comment: Your question is not clear. You WANT to go to top and it doesn't or you do NOT want to go to top and it does? Do _some actions_ have `return false` or `e.preventDefault` among them?

Comment: It seems to be the right answer !! Thank you very much.

Comment: What answer? That you must remove return false or add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `preventDefault` method:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //some actions
}
```

You can put the `preventDefault` call before or after your actions, depending on what fallback behaviour you want. If you put it first the link will never be followed. If you put it last, the link will be followed if the script crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<script>
    $("#link").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        //some actions
    }
</script>
```